Postgresql RDS - Error: must be member of role
I am in the middle of trying to migrate our Postgresql on an EC2 to Postgresql RDS. When I dump one of the DBs and restore it in RDS. One of the users pops up and gives "Error: must be member of role:"". I've checked the user and it doesn't own any schemas, tables, sequences, or the db. It's just a R/W user. I've seen this issue if the user was an owner of any sort of schema or db but not when it has no ownership. And it's just the one user giving this error, the others work just fine.
Any assistance or ideas would be appreciated.
I know about restoring the database with --no-privileges, but this is preferably non-optional as I have to do this multiple time and recreating databases and going through to setup the users for every database that could give this issue is not ideal.
